# Combining and modifying objects from an array in powershell to create a new array

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I have a csv with columns that contain a user's first name last name. I have firgured out how to import the csv data from each column using:

```
$firstname = Import-csv .\data.csv | select-object "Employee First Name" 
$lastname = Import-csv .\data.csv | select-object "Employee Last Name"
```

I have also figured out that:

```
$username=$firstname.substring(0,1)+$lastname
```

works when using `system.string` objects. The problem is I need to loop through all of names to create a new column with the username and I get the error

`System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'substring'`

I thought I could convert to string using `$firstname.ToString()` but I seem to have botched that. Any help is geatly appreciated as I am still trying to learn powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self expressive `$firstname`  is not a string. `$firstname` is an array of `string`.

Try :

```
$username = ($firstname[0]).substring(0,1)+$lastname[0]
```

you'd better use :

```
$employees = Import-csv .\data.csv
foreach ($employee in $employees)
{
  $username=($employee.'Employee First Name').substring(0,1)+($employee.'Employee Last Name')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to make a user name. So i'm not sure why you want to import one column at a time?

But this might work for you.

```
$names = Import-Csv .\test.csv
$userNames = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[String]'

foreach ($name in $names)
{
    $userNames.Add($($name.firstName.Substring(0,1) + $name.lastName))
}
```